# Homebrew observing quantum corpuscle - photon or electron or atom - whatever... How to?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons

How can I observe quantum effects of any corpuscle - photon or electron, or even atom.

Is there civil-grade not much expensive electron microscopes or any other ways?

I understand, that I can not build even small collider, because it is very expensive.

Is there any bypassing to observe ONE photon as corpuscle or electron or at least atom of anything heavy, like gold...

Kind of experiment..

**Update:** For example, I've heard, that quantum voting system - is already standard in euro-union and there are civil sub-contractors are producing such devices. And its are used across all Europe. I don't know for sure, is it true or false. But if this is true, this devise shall be based on `ONE-photon emitter` and `ONE-photon receiver`, because of protocol design. If you could split beam into two separate, the same way polarized, you could eavesdrop channel. So, photon must be alone, without 'company'...

So, I'm asking - how to build such emitter and receiver, at least??.. Experiment - is ours friend?? hello?

---

And thereafter, I want to entangle two corpuscles and observe it's super-position collapse... Could somebody put me on the right way?

[image]

Comment: see  https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/

Answer (score -1):

You can check this Quantum Microscope simulator:

https://energywavetheory.com/project/qscope/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T306LRHWEpw

It is a simulator but it may be enough for your purposes.

However, you need to be aware that it has been implemented using models other than quantum mechanics. It's just that the current state of quantum mechanics is so absurd that nothing can be simulated with it. Not to mention that the engineer implementing it would have to spend half his life going through the meanders of quantum mechanics to find out that it just doesn't work :).

Anticipating the criticism that is about to pour out. Maybe someone will indicate a similar simulator based on quantum mechanics models?